# Nice way to register components

Tags: c++, components

I have the following classes:

```
class A {
public:
  bool canHandleIt(...) = 0;
  void handleIt(...) = 0;
}


class B {
  vector<A> handlers;
  void request(...)
  {
    foreach (handler in handlers){
      if (handler.canHanleIt(...)){
        handler.handleIt(...);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So A is a request handler interface. B gets requests and tries to respond them. My question is how should I register implementations of A-s in B. My ideas:

1.
I instantiates handlers in B, and add them to the list in it's constructor for example. My problem with it is every time i create a new handler, I have to modify B.

2.
Create a new class C, which has references to handlers and B too, so it could register handlers in B, if i add a `registerHandler` method to B. The problem is same as with #1, with every new handler I have to edit C.

3.
Let the handler list and `registerHandler` method be static, then implementations of A-s could register themself. This way the list would become globally accessible, which I think isn't a good practice.

Basically what i want is whenever i create a new type of A, it can be used by B without edit nothing but the new type of A. Is there any pattern or common solution to this problem?

Comment: You likely do not need `bool canHandleIt(...)`. `bool handleIt(...)` might be good enough.

Comment: boost::any (structure) might be useful for passing the argument(s) to each handlers